# ERROR: Spring Boot, amazonRDS, org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Getting below error while running Spring boot application with Amazon RDS.

**ERROR :**

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'amazonRDS': Invocation of init method failed;
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no EC2
 meta data available, because the application is not running in the EC2
 environment. Region detection is only possible if the application is
 running on a EC2 instance  at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
> ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:741)
 ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]    at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
 ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
 ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
 ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]     at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
 [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
 [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
 [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
 [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]  at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
 [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
```

Let me know how to integrate my Amazon RDS database and spring boot application.

Comment: Please format the stack trace and add the code that causes this.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818092/spring-boot-startup-error-for-aws-application-there-is-not-ec2-meta-data-avail